# iOS app rejected while google authentication failed

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

My app is using google sign-in only for registration and login, I gave a demo gmail account which I created for Apple review purposes only. But when the reviewer at apple tried to login with demo account, google marked this login as suspicious and blocked signin as it was used in a different region, Because of this issue Apple reviewer reject my application.

Is there any way to make Gmail account work on Apple site without being blocked by Google?

Comment: you have manually login option in your app ?

Comment: if apple ask then you give demo account credential otherwise don't give. they will check with their credentials.

Comment: no, app doesn't have manual login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this issue by doing following steps.

1. If Google blocks any access they send you an email asking, is that
   you or someone else. Open the link in the email and mark it **Yes
   it's me**
2. Add recovery email to your account in the security section, and mention this email in notes on itunes Connect where you gave demo credentials to login. So if the verification screen comes up recovery email can be used to verify and login.
3. In the Google account settings > Security > Allow less security app . turn on this option.